# Summing one item in my dataframe tuple, across the row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe that consists of the sum total of the second item in each cell (row-wise).  So, in my dataframe below, I would like a column with the sum total of:
0.001658, 0.011609, 0.01495, 0.016584, 0.014925, etc...

And then continue that down for all of the rows..

I am having trouble writing the for loop that will iterate over this to sum the second item, row-wise and create a new column for it.

My dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: I'm on my phone so can't check it but I think `DF.applymap(lambda t: t[1]).sum(axis =1)` should work

Answer (score 4):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)],
        [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)],
        [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)],
    ])
print(df)

        0       1       2
0  (1, 2)  (3, 4)  (5, 6)
1  (1, 2)  (3, 4)  (5, 6)
2  (1, 2)  (3, 4)  (5, 6)
```

You can use `numpy` to convert to a 3-D array and slice the second component as you'd like

```
d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df.values.tolist())[:, :, 1], df.index, df.columns)
print(d2)

   0  1  2
0  2  4  6
1  2  4  6
2  2  4  6
```

Then `sum(1)`, the `1` specifies to sum accross rows

```
d2.sum(1)

0    12
1    12
2    12
dtype: int64
```

---

Or you could have done the whole thing in `numpy` making it even quicker.

```
pd.Series(np.array(df.values.tolist())[:, :, 1].sum(1), df.columns)

0    12
1    12
2    12
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I am receiving an error, `too many indices for array`.  Do you know what could be causing this?  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Gary you have to understand that you are asking questions about what is happening on your computer without letting us know what the data is.  You pasted an image which is bad form for several reasons.  One reason is that what the data looks like may not be the data you actually have.  What it seems like (maybe, because I'm guessing, because I don't have your data) is that you have a 2-D array of strings where the strings look like tuples.  Then when you use my suggestion, it's using indexers assuming there are 3 dimensions when there are only two.  ***solution*** post actual data.

Comment: I apologize for not posting data.  It's just a very, very large dataset!  With your hypothesis of my problem where the 2-D array of string looks like tuples, do you know a method of solving that problem?

Comment: @Gary partial data is ok.  It's just inefficient when you don't because we see this issue all the time.  Someone doesn't post data, an answer will come in and the question asker will say "Yeah, but... it doesn't work"  And 9 times out of 10 its because there is a nuance that was left out that could have been avoided had the asker included the actual data they are working with.

Comment: I 100% understand.  I respect your support very much and will troubleshoot my data type problems and then try your solution.  I'll be mindful of it going forward!  #NotMyPresident